# Como asignar un Tipo y Tamaño de Fuente especifico a varios Botones al mismo tiempo? Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy diseñando una interfaz básica para una calculadora en Python 3.8 (usando el módulo tkinter), y quiero que en vez de estar **repitiendo por cada linea el tipo y tamaño de fuente a usar**, pudiera hacer que **todos los botones tomaran dicha fuente de una vez (en este caso, Roboto Cn, 14)** sin estar escribiéndola a cada rato. Esto es posible? Les agradezco mucho ya que soy novato en esto y recién estoy comenzando. A continuación dejo el código que hasta el momento llevo, para ver como lo puedo mejorar. Gracias.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.title("Calculadora Basica")
miFrame=Frame(root)
miFrame.pack()

"-------- Pantalla --------"
pantalla=Entry(miFrame)
pantalla.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=4)
pantalla.config(bg="white", justify="right")

"-------- Fila 1 --------"
boton7=Button(miFrame, text="7", width=3, bd=1, relief="ridge", font=("Roboto Cn",14))
boton7.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=2)
boton8=Button(miFrame, text="8", width=3, bd=1, relief="ridge", font=("Roboto Cn",14))
boton8.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=2)
boton9=Button(miFrame, text="9", width=3, bd=1, relief="ridge", font=("Roboto Cn",14))
boton9.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=2)
botonMult=Button(miFrame, text="*", width=3, bd=1, relief="ridge", font=("Roboto Cn",14))
botonMult.grid(row=2, column=4, padx=2)

"-------- Fila 2 --------"
boton4=Button(miFrame, text="4", width=3, bd=1, relief="ridge", font=("Roboto Cn",14))
boton4.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=2)
boton5=Button(miFrame, text="5", width=3, bd=1, relief="ridge", font=("Roboto Cn",14))
boton5.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=2)
boton6=Button(miFrame, text="6", width=3, bd=1, relief="ridge", font=("Roboto Cn",14))
boton6.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=2)
botonRest=Button(miFrame, text="-", width=3, bd=1, relief="ridge", font=("Roboto Cn",14))
botonRest.grid(row=3, column=4, padx=2)

"-------- Fila 3 --------"
boton1=Button(miFrame, text="1", width=3, bd=1, relief="ridge", font=("Roboto Cn",14))
boton1.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=2)
boton2=Button(miFrame, text="2", width=3, bd=1, relief="ridge", font=("Roboto Cn",14))
boton2.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=2)
boton3=Button(miFrame, text="3", width=3, bd=1, relief="ridge", font=("Roboto Cn",14))
boton3.grid(row=4, column=3, padx=2)
botonMas=Button(miFrame, text="+", width=3, bd=1, relief="ridge", font=("Roboto Cn",14))
botonMas.grid(row=4, column=4, padx=2)

"-------- Fila 4 --------"
botonDiv=Button(miFrame, text="/", width=3, bd=1, relief="ridge", font=("Roboto Cn",14))
botonDiv.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=2)
boton0=Button(miFrame, text="0", width=3, bd=1, relief="ridge", font=("Roboto Cn",14))
boton0.grid(row=5, column=2, padx=2)
botonDec=Button(miFrame, text=",", width=3, bd=1, relief="ridge", font=("Roboto Cn",14))
botonDec.grid(row=5, column=3, padx=2)
botonIgual=Button(miFrame, text="=", width=3, bd=1, relief="ridge", font=("Roboto Cn",14))
botonIgual.grid(row=5, column=4, padx=2)

"-------- Ejecutar --------"
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

### Usar `tkinter.Font`

Puedes crear un objeto `Font` con las características que quieras y luego asignarlo a los widgets que quieras:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import Font

root = tk.Tk() 

btn_font = Font(family="Roboto Cn", size=14) 

boton = tk.Button(roo, text="Hola", width=3, bd=1, relief="ridge", font=btn_font)
```

Solo ten en cuenta que se debe instanciar después de que exista una ventana principal (`root`).

Si posterior mente modificas el objeto `Font` (por ejemplo modificando el tamaño de la fuente vía `btn_font.configure(size=17)`), todos los cambios se reflejarán de forma inmediata en todos los widgets que lo usen.

### Usar una clase

La otra opción es usar una clase que derive de `tkinter.Button` y inicializar el botón como quieras.Luego usas tu clase personalizada en vez de `tkinter.Button`.

```
import tkinter as tk


class CalcButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault("font", ("Roboto Cn", 14))
        kwargs.setdefault("width", 3)
        kwargs.setdefault("bd", 1)
        kwargs.setdefault("relief", "ridge")
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Calculadora Basica")
mi_frame = tk.Frame(root)
mi_frame.pack()

# -------- Pantalla --------
pantalla = tk.Entry(mi_frame)
pantalla.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=4)
pantalla.config(bg="white", justify="right")

# -------- Fila 1 --------
boton7 = CalcButton(mi_frame, text="7")
boton7.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=2)
boton8 = CalcButton(mi_frame, text="8")
boton8.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=2)
boton9 = CalcButton(mi_frame, text="9")
boton9.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=2)
botonMult = CalcButton(mi_frame, text="*")
botonMult.grid(row=2, column=4, padx=2)

# -------- Fila 2 --------
boton4 = CalcButton(mi_frame, text="4")
boton4.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=2)
boton5 = CalcButton(mi_frame, text="5")
boton5.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=2)
boton6 = CalcButton(mi_frame, text="6")
boton6.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=2)
botonRest = CalcButton(mi_frame, text="-")
botonRest.grid(row=3, column=4, padx=2)

# -------- Fila 3 --------
boton1 = CalcButton(mi_frame, text="1")
boton1.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=2)
boton2 = CalcButton(mi_frame, text="2")
boton2.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=2)
boton3 = CalcButton(mi_frame, text="3")
boton3.grid(row=4, column=3, padx=2)
botonMas = CalcButton(mi_frame, text="+")
botonMas.grid(row=4, column=4, padx=2)

# -------- Fila 4 --------
botonDiv = CalcButton(mi_frame, text="/")
botonDiv.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=2)
boton0 = CalcButton(mi_frame, text="0")
boton0.grid(row=5, column=2, padx=2)
botonDec = CalcButton(mi_frame, text=",")
botonDec.grid(row=5, column=3, padx=2)
botonIgual = CalcButton(mi_frame, text="=")
botonIgual.grid(row=5, column=4, padx=2)

# -------- Ejecutar --------
root.mainloop()
```

### Usar `tkinter.ttk.Button` y `tkinter.ttk.Style`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Calculadora Basica")

style = ttk.Style() 
style.configure('C.TButton', font=("Roboto Cn", 14))
style.configure('C.TButton', relief="ridge")
style.configure('C.TButton', width=3)
style.configure('C.TButton', bd=1)


mi_frame = tk.Frame(root)
mi_frame.pack()

# -------- Pantalla --------
pantalla = tk.Entry(mi_frame)
pantalla.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=4)
pantalla.config(bg="white", justify="right")

# -------- Fila 1 --------
boton7 = ttk.Button(mi_frame, text="7", style='C.TButton')
boton7.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=2)
boton8 = ttk.Button(mi_frame, text="8", style='C.TButton')
boton8.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=2)
boton9 = ttk.Button(mi_frame, text="9", style='C.TButton')
boton9.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=2)
botonMult = ttk.Button(mi_frame, text="*", style='C.TButton')
botonMult.grid(row=2, column=4, padx=2)

# -------- Fila 2 --------
boton4 = ttk.Button(mi_frame, text="4", style='C.TButton')
boton4.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=2)
boton5 = ttk.Button(mi_frame, text="5", style='C.TButton')
boton5.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=2)
boton6 = ttk.Button(mi_frame, text="6", style='C.TButton')
boton6.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=2)
botonRest = ttk.Button(mi_frame, text="-", style='C.TButton')
botonRest.grid(row=3, column=4, padx=2)

# -------- Fila 3 --------
boton1 = ttk.Button(mi_frame, text="1", style='C.TButton')
boton1.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=2)
boton2 = ttk.Button(mi_frame, text="2", style='C.TButton')
boton2.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=2)
boton3 = ttk.Button(mi_frame, text="3", style='C.TButton')
boton3.grid(row=4, column=3, padx=2)
botonMas = ttk.Button(mi_frame, text="+", style='C.TButton')
botonMas.grid(row=4, column=4, padx=2)

# -------- Fila 4 --------
botonDiv = ttk.Button(mi_frame, text="/", style='C.TButton')
botonDiv.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=2)
boton0 = ttk.Button(mi_frame, text="0", style='C.TButton')
boton0.grid(row=5, column=2, padx=2)
botonDec = ttk.Button(mi_frame, text=",", style='C.TButton')
botonDec.grid(row=5, column=3, padx=2)
botonIgual = ttk.Button(mi_frame, text="=", style='C.TButton')
botonIgual.grid(row=5, column=4, padx=2)

# -------- Ejecutar --------
root.mainloop()
```

---

Independientemente del tema de la fuente, en casos como éste en el que se genera un grid del mismo objeto con las mismas características, puedes usar ciclos para generar los botones dinámicamente:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Calculadora Basica")

mi_frame = tk.Frame(root)
mi_frame.pack()

# -------- Pantalla --------
pantalla = tk.Entry(mi_frame)
pantalla.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=4)
pantalla.config(bg="white", justify="right")

filas = [["7", "8", "9", "*"],
         ["4", "5", "6", "-"],
         ["1", "2", "3", "+"],
         ["/", "0", ",", "="]]

for x, fila in enumerate(filas):
    for y, texto in enumerate(fila):
        boton = tk.Button(
            mi_frame, text=texto, font=("Roboto Cn", 14),
            relief="ridge", width=3, bd=1)
        boton.grid(row=x + 2, column=y + 1, padx=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Gracias amigo por tus invaluables aportes. Voy a revisar y cualquier cosa le comento. Muy amable.

Comment: Amigo, se que cada quien va con sus gustos, pero hablando de diseño y estetica, que tipo y tamaña de fuente se suele usar por costumbre para el diseño de interfaces graficas? me gusta inclinarme por fuentes planas y finas. Me gusta mucho por ejemplo la fuente y tamaña que sale por defecto en el titulo de las ventanas, pero trato de aplicarlo por ejemplo en un Label o Entry cualquiera y no me queda igual. Como hago yo para saber que fuente y tamaño usa la propiedad title de las ventanas? Quiero que mis interfaces se vean bien diseñadas y profesionales. Muchas gracias.